# south migrate myapp 0001 --fake

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south

I'm reading [South's documentation about how to convert an app](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html).

I don't understand the `0001` part inside the example `./manage.py migrate myapp 0001 --fake`, because it seems there are no references in the docs about the meaning of this 4-digit number.

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#migrate), it is just a shortcut, to save typing.

If you check your `migrations` directory, you would see a python file called: `0001_migration_name.py`. South simply provides you a way to run the migration by specifying only digits, a prefix of the migration name.

Note that if you would run `./manage.py migrate myapp 000` while having several migrations, e.g.:

```
0001_initial_migration
0002_add_username
```

you would receive an error, since `south` would not identify a single unique migration by the prefix you've provided.

FYI, here is the source code of [`guess_migration()`](https://bitbucket.org/andrewgodwin/south/src/0e17add9b5e0f30f7cf5acf47961eea6a7f4032c/south/migration/base.py#cl-198), that tries to match the migration by prefix.